# Geonetwork 3 war file deploying tomcat 7 issue

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, geonetwork

I'm trying to deploy geonetwork.war file to tomcat 7. I've tried a lot of diferent ways to doing this but all the time failed.
OS : Windows 7
Java Version : JDK 1.7
Tomcat 7

Is there anybody who can success this?